# How can I change displayed module from which a custom exception is traced?

Tags: python, exception

When I've tried raising a custom `exception` using my own package, I get a traceback resembling the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pdfshelltools\examples\change_error_module_mwe\run_this_one.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise_error()
  File "D:\pdfshelltools\examples\change_error_module_mwe\MyPackage\MyModule.py", line 4, in raise_error
    raise MyError()
MyPackage.exceptions.MyError
[Finished in 147ms]
```

My issue is with the `MyPackage.exceptions.MyError` part. I'd like to change that to just `MyPackage.MyError`, feeling that the other is too verbose with no great justification in my use case. This may be wrongheaded on my part—and I can be persuaded otherwise if so—but other packages don't seem to run on to this degree, and I'd like mine to be that way too.

I have tried changing the `__module__` attribute of my custom exception, but I haven't found a way to make that work.

Here's a script that will create a MWE inside a directory called `change_error_module_mwe` in the current working directory.

```
from pathlib import Path


EXAMPLEDIR = Path('change_error_module_mwe')
PACKAGE = Path('MyPackage')
EXAMPLEDIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
Path(EXAMPLEDIR / PACKAGE).mkdir(exist_ok=True)

with open(EXAMPLEDIR / PACKAGE / 'MyModule.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("""from MyPackage.exceptions import MyError

def raise_error():
    raise MyError()
""")

with open(EXAMPLEDIR / PACKAGE / '__init__.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("")

with open(EXAMPLEDIR / PACKAGE / 'exceptions.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('class MyError(Exception):\n\tpass\n')

with open(EXAMPLEDIR / 'run_this_one.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('from MyPackage.MyModule import raise_error\n\n\nraise_error()\n')
```

Comment: How about just using `raise Exception('MyError')`?

Comment: In the more complex code I'm trying to write, I'm doing more inside the custom error than merely `pass`ing. Everything I've read about exceptions goes on about custom classes, so I thought that was the way to go. It is interesting to see how this behaves differently though.

Comment: This approach would make it difficult (impossible?) for clients to tell them apart if your package has more than one kind.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want users to see a full traceback from an internal module of your package, I think your best bet is to catch it on a top-level module of your package and re-raise the exception from `None` (which will cut the entire internal traceback). Example:

```
try:
    open('database.sqlite')
except OSError:
    raise RuntimeError from None
```

You can use that approach and have a module that is an error handler, so all Exceptions would be thrown from there.

Comment: `raise RuntimeError from None` → `SyntaxError`.